# Bake priority 0 blocks only and ignore priority 1 and higher?

Tags: baking

I'm over delegated and wish to only bake priority 0 blocks as it requires the same bond for priority 1 bakes.  Is there any way I can make my baker only bake priority 0 blocks and ignore priority 1 and higher?

Answer (score 3):

The tezos baker binary accepts a parameter `max-priority=1`

This is documented in the [official binary documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html)